# how to add subview programmatically behind storyboard sub view

Tags: ios

I have `UIViewController` which set top storyboard and having few subviews in storyboard. and I want to add a `UIImageView` programmatically and set it as a background view. so if I add a `UIImageView`, storyboard subviews are not visible.

> how can I send this `UIImageView` behind all the storyboard subviews?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to go with the `sendSubviewToBack:`

```
 UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank-background.jpg"];
        [self.view addSubview:imgView];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgView];
```

Answer (score 0):

use method of subview's "`bringSubViewToFront`".
like

```
  [parentView bringSubViewToFront:subViewImg];
```